# new Option(text, value, defaultSelected, selected);

Tags: javascript, form, html-select

Если создавать опцию как:

```
var option = new Option(text, value, defaultSelected, selected);
```

Возникает вопрос: для того, чтобы опция была "выбрана" ей ведь нужно поставить `defaultSelected` и `selected` в `true`, иначе она выбрана не будет. Зачем тогда вообще дублирование этих аргументов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как одно из применений:

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form'),
  select = document.getElementById('select'),
  resetButton = document.getElementById('reset');

select.options[0] = new Option('Option 1', 'opt1', false, true);
select.options[1] = new Option('Option 2', 'opt2', true, false);

resetButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  form.reset();
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <select id="select"></select>
</form>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

То есть, при инициализации мы явно указываем какая опция у нас выбрана (opt1), но при сбросе формы, выбирается уже опция у которой `isDefaultSelected` true (opt2).

Comment: Да я понимаю, но такая реализация выглядит весьма странно.

Comment: @1px_solid_black, почему же? Вполне реальная ситуация ... Есть селект, в нем дофлтное значение, человек выбирает другое, отправляет выбор на сервер, после этого у него всегда выводится то что он выбрал, но потом он хочет сбросить свой выбор (по умолчанию), тут то и приходит на помощь данный параметр.